# ng-model is not getting updated on selection change in select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I am new to angular so still struggling with basic things, here is a problem that I am facing. I have a few html elements that repeat with ng-repeat. One of the controls in it is a  dropdown.
I have attached ng-model with this .However on selection change the model is not getting updated.Not sure what the problem is. Pasting below the code.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Compare Tickers</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<!--        <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>-->
            <ul>
                <li id="control{{$index}}" ng-repeat="oneTickerInfo in tickerInfo">
                    Ticker Info : <input type="text">
                    <select  ng-model="selectedCache" ng-options="cache for cache in caches" ng-change="handleCacheSelectionChange()"></select>
                    <select ng-click="handleHostSelectEvent()" ng-init="selectedBox = boxes[0]" ng-model="selectedBox"  ng-options="box.box for box in boxes"></select>
                    [<a href ng-click="tickerInfo.splice($index, 1)">X</a>]
                </li>
                <li>
                    [<a href ng-click="tickerInfo.push({})">add</a>]
                </li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>
    <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 'use strict';

var app = angular.module('qaweb3App');

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function Hello($scope, $http) {


      $scope.tickerInfo = [
          {id:'1', cache:'adx',host:'tpa27'},
          {id:'1', cache:'asx',host:'tpa27'}
      ];

      $scope.caches = [];

      function process_response( data ) {
          var jsonArrayLen = data.length;
          for( var index=0; index < jsonArrayLen; index ++ ) {
              $scope.caches.push( data[index].cache.id);
          }
          /*$scope.selectedCache = $scope.caches[0];*/
          console.log( $scope.caches.toString() );
      }

      $http({method: 'JSONP', url: 'http://unixdeva10.factset.com:9643/jsonprouter?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&key=caches.json'}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              process_response(data);
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("Failed");
          });

       $scope.getHosts = function() {
          console.log("You clicked box");
      };

      $scope.handleCacheSelectionChange=function() {
          console.log("Selection has changed");
          console.log( " You have chosen selection " + $scope.selectedCache );
      }

  });
```

The selection always stays the first element inspite of the selection change.

**HTML Source**

```
<select ng-model="selectedCache" ng-options="cache for cache in caches" ng-
change="handleCacheSelectionChange()" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
<option value="0" selected="selected">adx</option>
```

Inside the handleCacheSelectionChange function the value of $scope.selectedCache is undefined.

**EDIT 1**

As per your suggestions I have tried the following:

*Javascript:*

$scope.tickerInfo = [
      "selectedCache1",
      "selectedCache2"
     ];

$scope.handleCacheSelectionChange=function(index) {
      console.log( " You have chosen selection " + index );

}

*HTML*

```
 <select  ng-model="$parent.tickerInfo[$index]" ng-options="cache.cacheName for cache in caches" ng-change="handleCacheSelectionChange($index)"></select>
```

Until now everything works fine.
 Now I have a href which is outside the ng-repeat, so to dynamically update tickerInfo with another entry we need the last index of the inner scope. I am not able to bind the local scope $index to the global scope $scope.currentIndex

```
[<a href ng-click="handleAddEvent($index)">add</a>]
```

Can some one give me some hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you create a fiddle/codepen or something please?

Comment: I do not see ngApp in your mark up. How did you make it work without it?

Comment: You are bound to get quicker help at a higher quality if you include in your question only short pieces of highly relevant code along with a demo which demonstrates the problem. If the answer(s) below don't solve your problem, please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem here is that you are using ng-repeat in the form.

ng-repeat creates a [new scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L357) (credits to [Zack Snow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25381/zach-snow)), which means that your view code is editing a different `$selectedCache`. So you don't get the two-way data binding that you were expecting.

I think [this short tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc) from egghead.io would be helpful.

So effectively, your controller code is interacting with the cache object under the controller $scope. On the other hand, the cache object in the view is interacting within that repeated child scope.

To fix the problem, append `selectedCache` object in a data object under `$scope`, such as `$scope.tickerInfo[$index].selectedCache`. In this way, when ng-select changes the selected cache, it changes the one bind with the controller `$scope`

Comment: `ng-repeat` doesn't create an isolate scope, but it does create a [*new* scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L357). Which means each `ng-model` is writing to a different `selectedCache`.